# How can I prove that $2\mathbb{Z}$ is NOT a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}$, as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Tags: modules, direct-sum

I know that $\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}+\{0\}$ (with "+" I mean "direct sum"). Is this enough to prove that $2\mathbb{Z}$ is NOT a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}$,  as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Comment: Your first equality is wrong as not all the integers are even. Did you mean perhaps to write "isomorphic"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that for any

$$\;m\Bbb Z\le\Bbb Z\;\;,\;\;2\Bbb Z\cap m\Bbb Z\neq0$$

and thus $\;2\Bbb Z\;$ , or for that matter any non-trivial subgroup of the integers, cannot be a non-trivial direct summand.